# Преобразование массива. Помогите понять функцию, php

Tags: php

```
    $arr = array(
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(1, 2, 4)
);
// php >= 5.6 $arr = array_merge(...$arr);
$arr = array_reduce($arr, 'array_merge', array());
$max = max($arr);
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($e) use ($max) { return $e != $max; });
echo
    implode('<br>', $arr),
    'Sum: ', array_sum($arr), '<br>',
    'Product: ', array_product($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# есть двумерный массив (матрица)
$arr = array(
array(1, 2, 3),
array(1, 2, 4)
);
// php >= 5.6 $arr = array_merge(...$arr);

# array_reduce применяет функцию к каждому элементу массива (но только верхнего уровня)
# получается где то так
# $arr = array_merge(array_merge(array(), $arr[0]), $arr[1])
# это называется сделать массив плоским (flat array)
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array
$arr = array_reduce($arr, 'array_merge', array());
# в $arr теперь (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4)

# максимальный элемент и в Африке максимальный, то есть, 4
$max = max($arr);

# эта конструкция отфильтровывает с массива неугодные элементы
# которые определяются безымяной функцией
# в данном случае она выбросит максимальные элементы, то есть, 4
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($e) use ($max) { return $e != $max; });
# в $arr теперь (1, 2, 3, 1, 2)
# можно было бы и обычный цыкл сделать, но в функциональном программировании это не модно.

# теперь дело за малым - вывести результат на экран
# и сумму/произведение
echo
implode('<br>', $arr),
'Sum: ', array_sum($arr), '<br>',
'Product: ', array_product($arr);
```

Видимо кто то почитал много о хаскеле и функциональном программировании и решил применить всю мощь. Получилось достаточно компактно, но удивительно.